# Selected Image is not displaying in image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

My issue is,In one view I'm having many image views like frames saving single image in single image view and I'm using action sheet in that one button edit to display selected image to next view while I'm selecting image action sheet is displayed and while clicking edit button it is going to next view but selected image is not displayed in imageview.This is my code.any answer related is appreciated .Thank you!
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNva.png !
 second image is when we select particular image action sheet will be displayed in that I'm having edit button if I click edit the image which is selected should go to second view but I'm not getting image in image view .I'm getting output like this(i.e.,third image)
But I need to get selected image also

This is my code.
//image,image1,image2,....image6 are different imageviews in collage view
// to save image in imageview which was parsed from another view.

```
switch (collageView.selectImageTag) {
imageView.image=nil;
case 1:
imageView.image=collageView.image.image;    //collage view is the object of        another viewcontroller

break;

case 2:
imageView.image= collageView.image1.image;

break;
case 3:
imageView.image=collageView.image2.image;

break;
case 4:
imageView.image=collageView.image3.image;

break;
case 5:
imageView.image=collageView.image4.image;

break;
case 6:
imageView.image=collageView.image5.image;

break;
case 7:
imageView.image= collageView.image6.image;

break;
default:
imageView.image=collageView.Newimage;
break;
}


//collage view for selecting particular image



else if([title isEqual:@"Edit"])
{
 SecondViewController *secview=[[SecondViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 if (self.selectImageTag==1) {
 Newimage=self.image.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 NSLog(@"%@",Newimage);
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==2)
 {
 Newimage=self.image1.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==3)
 {
 Newimage=self.image2.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==4)
 {
 Newimage=self.image3.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==5)
 {
 Newimage=self.image4.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==6)
 {
 Newimage=self.image5.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 else if (self.selectImageTag==7)
 {
 Newimage=self.image6.image;
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 }
 secview.imageView.image=Newimage;
 [self presentViewController:secview animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue.I'm not getting what's going on wrong

Comment: Two things: Check `collageView.selectImageTag` value and check `imageView` is nil or not.

Comment: Thanq for your response @Mrunal But It is not nil